# Looking for a PromQL expression for BHTA in the last 24 hours

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

Basically, show the max number of transactions reached in any particular hour during the last 24 hours. I think some folks call this the "Peak BHTA" (Busy Hour Transaction Attempt).

I came to this expression so far:

```
max_over_time(sum(increase(http_count[1h]))[24h:])
```

I am probably in the right track but I think I am messing up the range vectors somehow.

Any advice is welcome.

Thanks.

----------- Edit 1

@markalex made me realize my question is ambiguous. So I clarified in the comments below.

Comment: By any particular hour do you mean 05:00 - 06:00, or any window of time with length of an hour?

Comment: Any window of time of 60 minutes. It could that the busiest hour happened from 5:15 to 6:15 as an example. I don't particularly care about reporting the time range, I mostly want the amount of requests it that busiest hour.

In that sense, I see that given a 24 hours period, I want to slide a window of 1 hour in size, this window moves minute by minute (or whatever the scraping frequency is).  I other words I have  24*60 buckets or windows, so I need to find the max one.

Comment: Then query you came up yourself does exactly what you want. You range selectors are correct, and no changes needed.

Comment: One thing regarding comments. It's better you do the opposite to what you've done: edit question to provide full info, and mention in comments with tag of user that you updated it (in case user forgot to follow it). Comments are seen as ephemeral,  and should be expected to be deleted at any time, thus any information important for the question should be in question itself.